# unit8 array to bytes array

Tags: python, python-2.7, swig

I have a `uint8_t_arr` object `foo`.  I also have a python `in`t for the array size called `bar`.

How do I convert `foo` to a `bytearray` or `bytes` object?

It seems crazy to me I can only access one item at a time with `uint8_t_arr_getitem`.  Is there no way in python to access a range in this object?  Or just get the whole thing in a buffer?  `foo.__something__`?  `foo.thething`?

Comment: This sounds like the kind of thing where `bytearray(foo)` or `bytearray(memoryview(foo))` would be the way to go.

Comment: @user2357112  "TypeError: 'SwigPyObject' object is not iterable"  is what I get when I try that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing `foo` is the swig `uint8` array, and `foo_size` is the number of elements in the array:

```
foostring = str()
for i in range(0, foo_size):
  foostring += struct.pack("B", int(uint8_t_arr_getitem(pkt, i)))
```

On the platform I was testing, the `uint8_t_arr_getitem()` function was returning a long value.  This was causing an error, so I wrapped in an `int()`